# Examples of 3-transitive expander family of Schreier graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, expander-graphs

What are examples of expander family of 3-transitive Schreier graphs? 
Meaning for an action that is 3-transitive.

It is better to have an option for randomization. We know that choosing 2 elements at random in a simple Lie group leads to expander family of Cayley graphs.

Is the same thing true for example, in case we randomize elements in Schreier graph of $\mathrm{PSL}_2$ acting on the projective plane?

Let's ask this formally: Given $\epsilon$, is there a family of bounded degree Schreier graphs with a 3-transitive group action such that if I randomize x generators,  I have $\epsilon$-expansion in probability p independent of n(the number of vertices of the graph).

I am looking for a known result similar to this.  Or maybe references.

And if not 3, then 2-transitive would be OK.

Thanks

Comment: There are known examples of such families (e.g. using Brooks' spectral gap for congruence actions of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$). Could you be more precise? to me the question is presently written in a too informal style to really know what you wish to have.

Comment: Added formality. I don't know what results are there, so I have asked that informally. Anything close to what I wrote would be nice. If you need to take specific generators for each $n$ , that would be interesting too.

Comment: So you're looking for a family $(G_i,X_i)$ with $G_i$ a finite group acting on $X_i$ (3-transitively) such that for some $x$ and each $\varepsilon>0$, the probability $p_i=p_i(x,\varepsilon)$ that a random $x$-tuple in $G_i$ (using uniform probability on $G_i^x$) is generates $G_i$ with $\varepsilon$ spectral gap on $\ell^2(X_i)$, satisfies $\liminf p_i>0$. (This is not exactly what you're asking, but roughly is it?)

Comment: Yes. looking for a result or related tools/references.

Comment: Also, if you have certain predetermined generators, that would be fine.

Comment: With predetermined generators, I mentioned Brooks' result: hence for each fixed generating subset of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, you have expansion for the Schreier graphs on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})$ when $p$ ranges over primes.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more specific? ( a paper)

Comment: Brooks proved the spectral gap for representations of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ factoring through a congruence quotient ($\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ when $n$ ranges over positive integers). In particular, the $\ell^2(\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}))$ when $p$ ranges over primes, has a spectral gap.

Comment: Couldn't find such a paper. Could you be more specific? Do you remember any detail from the title/abstract? What is the name of the method.

Comment: I thinks it's: R. Brooks, The ﬁrst eigenvalue in a tower of coverings. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 13 (1985),no. 2, 137-140. But actually the spectral gap itself for congruence subgroups is rather due to Selberg: On the estimation of Fourier coefficients of modular forms, Proc. Symp. Pure Math. VII, Amer. Math. Soc.(1965), 1-15.

Comment: Thanks a lot! LOL, I searched for Shimon Brooks whom I know a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was solved.

It is a bit long for here but given $G=SL(2,p)$,  $Cay(G, S) $ expander, 
we can see that  $Sc:=Sch[G,P^1(F_p),S]$ is also an expander, by comparing their mixing time and find it is less than that of the cayley graph.

The action is 3-transitive because the action of $GL$ is.

The idea is that  $s_t ... \cdot s_1 $ is mixed after $t$ step and that is what acts on any element in the Scherier graph. We divide it into classes in which  $s_t ...  s_1 \cdot x = y$ , and use the mixing condition.

Comment: Actually for a field $K$ the $\mathrm{SL}_2(K)$-action on distinct triples of $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$ has its orbits indexed by ${K^*}/{K^*}^2$, so is not transitive in general (for a finite field of odd characteristic it has 2 orbits). That is, it's not 3-transitive, albeit quite close. If $-1$ is not a square in $K$ (i.e., if $K$ has cardinal in $4\mathbf{Z}+3$), the action is however transitive on 3-element subsets, and also in this case the $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$-action is 3-transitive.